# stored procedure always taking first parameter from the code

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[T_TransactionSummary]  
 @locations nvarchar
AS
    BEGIN 
..............
.............
AND (Location_tbl.Locid IN (@locations))
```

my locid field is integer
this locid coming from my listbox.if i select one item 1 locid will come.if i select 2 item 2 locid will come..
I've got a ListBox which populates the @locations parameter (an integer), I took my listbox value like this

```
cnt = LSTlocations.SelectedItems.Count
 Dim list As New List(Of Integer)
        Dim locid As Integer
        If cnt > 0 Then
            For i = 0 To cnt - 1
                Dim locationanme As String = LSTlocations.SelectedItems(i).ToString
                locid = RecordID("Locid", "Location_tbl", "LocName", locationanme)
                list.Add(locid)
            Next
End If
 Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim cmd23 As New SqlCommand("T_TransactionSummary", con.connect)
        cmd23.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd23.Parameters.Add("@locations", SqlDbType.Int).Value = String.Join(",", list)
        da.SelectCommand = cmd23
        da.Fill(ds)
```

now my locationid from listbox is passing to stored procedure 1,2,3, only . but stored procedure always taking first value(i mean in this case taking 1).

Comment: Did you perform any simple debugging first? Like `PRINT @locations;`?

Comment: no sir...why i have to do that?

Comment: Because in this case it would have revealed that the value you were passing was getting truncated.

Answer (score 7):

First, [you absolutely need to define a length for your parameter](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)... what you currently have is a string that is being truncated at the first character.

```sql
DECLARE @locations NVARCHAR;
SET @locations = '1,2,3';
SELECT @locations;
```

Result:

```sql
1
```

You need to say

```sql
@locations VARCHAR(MAX)
```

You don't need `NVARCHAR` to store a comma-separated list of integers. (I assume you may have a long list of integers, but perhaps `MAX` could be `8000` instead.)

Then, you can't say `IN (@locations)` - this will not work correctly, either you will get an error message about converting `'1,2,3...'` to an int, or it just won't find the value - that is comparing to the whole string, not the set. So you could do this with dynamic SQL, e.g.

```sql
SET @sql = @sql + ' WHERE locations IN (' + @locations + ') ...;';
```

But that is fraught with all kinds of other problems, including maintainability and exposure to SQL injection. I highly recommend table-valued parameters instead. Basically you create a type like this:

```sql
CREATE TYPE dbo.Integers AS TABLE(Item INT PRIMARY KEY);
```

Then you use the parameter this way:

```sql
@locations dbo.Integers READONLY
```

And you can say:

```sql
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @locations WHERE Item = Location_tbl.Locid)
```

In your VB.Net code, you populate your listbox selections into a DataTable (instead of an int or a string), and pass the DataTable as a parameter with `SqlDbType.Structured`. I have some examples here, but they're C#:

http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql

There is also [plenty of documentation on TVPs on MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx).

Comment: sir..what i have to change ..?

Comment: @user2878851 I think I've given pretty thorough and useful instructions here.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I agree.  Your answer looks pretty complete.

Comment: sir i executed first:CREATE TYPE dbo.Integers AS TABLE(Item INT PRIMARY KEY); then i added "@locations dbo.Integers READONLY" to my sp.but getting error  Must declare the scalar variable "@locations".

Comment: @user2878851 this isn't a "write all my code for me" forum. Especially when you only included a very brief segment of your original code in the first place. Did you see how I changed the use of the `@locations` variable? Perhaps I should have named it something different? Have you looked at any of the links I provided to use my answer to help you learn how to use these technologies?

Answer (score 1):

The following is the first problem.

```
cmd23.Parameters.Add("@locations", SqlDbType.Int).Value = String.Join(",", list)
```

You are adding the @locations parameter as an int.  When you assign the value to it VB is converting your string to an int.  Which means `"1,2,3,4"` is going to become `"1"`.

Change that to a `SqlDbType.VarChar`

---

As to the second, I'm not entirely sure you can do this:

```
AND (Location_tbl.Locid IN (@locations))
```

---

You might want to look into table value parameters instead.

Comment: @user2878851: Look at Aaron's answer.  The part where he tells you to change the sp parameter to `@locations dbo.Integers READONLY` is a TVP.

Comment: i just given in my stored procedure like this:@locations integer readonly..now i am getting error:The parameter "@locations" can not be declared READONLY since it is not a table-valued parameter.