# while using table valued parameter getting scalar variable error in sp

Tags: sql-server, table-valued-parameters

i created table valued parameter like this:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ss AS TABLE(ss1 NVARCHAR(5));
```

then i wrote my stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[T_TransactionSummary] 
 @locations dbo.ss readonly
as
begin
...............
.............
AND (Location_tbl.Locid IN (@locations))
```

while executing this i am getting error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@locations".

What is wrong with my stored procedure

Comment: I've never used these, but wouldn't you have to SELECT from that parameter since the type is a TABLE result?

Comment: try: `AND (Location_tbl.Locid IN (select ss1 from @locations))`

Comment: Like as mentioned above. You can achieve the same approach by JOIN-ing with.

Comment: yes i miss the very first line in OP. BTW i delete comment as you already got the answer.

Comment: Why `dbo.ss(ss1)`? Those aren't very useful or meaningful names at all. And why `NVARCHAR(5)` instead of an `INT`? What if the value is greater than 5 characters? Why does it need to be Unicode? In your other question, you said these were integers, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seriously? [I showed you here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19500374/61305) that you can't use `IN (@TVP)` but instead must use a different technique, e.g. `WHERE EXISTS`:

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @locations WHERE ss1 = Location_tbl.Locid)
```

You can also say:

```
WHERE Location_tbl.Locid IN (SELECT ss1 FROM @locations)
```

Or:

```
INNER JOIN @locations AS x
ON x.ss1 = Location_tbl.Locid
```

The reason is that `@locations` is now, essentially, a table, not a variable or a literal value. You can't say `WHERE EmployeeID IN (dbo.Employees)`, right? You say `WHERE EmployeeID IN (SELECT EmployeeID FROM dbo.Employees)`.